# How to pass checkbox field to forms in django

Tags: python, django, forms, view

I know it might be a duplicate and or such a simple thing to ask here. Please assist if you know how to and ask for more details to help me sort my problem. DISCLAIMER: I am a django beginner.

I have a model which has a foreignkey field. I'd like to have the options passed into the foreignkey field display in checkboxes. I have not been able to get it work. These  are what I have

```
class Students(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200,unique=True,help_text="Student's name")
    form = models.ForeignKey(Form, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Form(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    form = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

All the options in form model are to be passed as check boxes in Students model

My forms.py is shown below

```
class StudentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, school, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StudentsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['form'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Form.objects.filter(school=school))    
    class Meta:
        model = Students
        fields = ("name",'form')
My views.py     
class StudentView(LoginRequiredMixin,CreateView):
    model = Students
    form_class = StudentsForm
    template_name = 'add_student.html'
    success_url = reverse_lazy('students')

    def get_form_kwargs(self):
        kwargs = super(StudentView, self).get_form_kwargs()
        kwargs['school'] = self.request.user.school
        return kwargs
```

Could I have the options as checkboxes, please???

Comment: `self.fields['form'] = forms.ModelChoiceField(
            queryset=Form.objects.filter(school=school)) ` in order to filter on `school` your Form class should have a school field.

Comment: @Vincent, yes it has a school field only that I hadn't included it.

Comment: Your Students class has a `school` field, but not the Form class. Please add all fields your Form class contains

Comment: Your future self could wish at some point in time that you had better not named a model "Form" to avoid confusion with the already existing form layer in Django.

Comment: @Vincent, added

Comment: Why would you want a checkbox instead of a dropdown select box? That saves you a lot of time.

Comment: @Vincent. So that I can use the checkboxes to querry other model objects...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using the default modelchoicefield for foreignkey relations which will give you a select box in your template. Javascript is not my best programming language but here's an answer on how to set this up:

models.py

```
from django.db import models


class School(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Students(models.Model):
    school = models.ForeignKey(School, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True, help_text="Student's name")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms

from .models import Students


class StudentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    school = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput)

    class Meta:
        model = Students
        fields = ("name", "school")
```

views.py

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from django.views.generic import FormView

from .forms import StudentsForm
from .models import Students, School


class StudentView(FormView):
    template_name = 'add_student.html'
    model = Students
    form_class = StudentsForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('students')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['schools'] = School.objects.all()
        return context
```

add_student.html

```
<form>
    {{ form.as_p }}

    <ul class="school__list">
        {% for school in schools %}
            <li class="school__list-item">{{ school.name }}
                <input type="checkbox" class="school__list-item-checkbox"
                       value="{{ school.id }}" name="school"/>
            </li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
</form>

<script>
    const schools = document.querySelectorAll('.school__list-item-checkbox');
    for (let i = 0; i < schools.length; i++) {
        schools[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        {# populate the hidden school field with the value that is checked here. #}
        })
    }
</script>
```

Comment: ,let me implement to see the outcome.